# Is this filter burnt and the capacitor damaged?

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount, emi-filtering

I'm repairing a Ring Chime PCB and have noticed what looks to be a burnt ceramic filter, and a capacitor next to it which is shorted.

[image: Image of the board]

The white rectangular component is labelled FL1 which makes me believe its a filter, and there is a brown spot on stop which I'd say looked burnt, but I don't know for sure. Next to it is the capacitor C51 which looks to have 2 different colours, green and black, and it measures as a direct short across it in both resistance and diode mode (I've taken it out of the circuit and confirmed its shorted). This capacitor is in series with the filter and the middle antenna pin.

No other component on the board seems damaged in any way (except for the board as a whole not turning on, which is out of scope of my question)

Both of those components were under a blob of hot glue which was used to keep the antenna wire in place.

Are these 2 components damaged, or is that expected?

Comment: I'm a repair tech. That filter definitely looks unhealthy. Seen many like this. Fuses and filters sometimes die like this - with burned dot

Comment: Ah, its definitely a burn then, OK. I'll need to replace that one then.

Comment: still measure its resistance when you remove it (or before). Just in case.

Comment: Good luck figuring out what C51 was supposed to be. The two colors indicate that it's probably some special type of capacitor, but I have no idea what type, and then you'd have to figure out what capacitance it needs to be, too. May be a good idea to ask a second question on here for "what is this capacitor"--I doubt you'll get a value without extensive reverse engineering and talking to an RF expert, but someone may at least know what the colors mean.

Comment: @Hearth Thanks, yeah, I think I'll do that. I thought the capacitor might be damaged since it appears a dead short across it but the colours are cleanly separated so probably some special filtering capacitor. I'll ask a specific question to address it

Comment: @QuickishFM The dead short is still an indication that it's damaged. I'm saying it's probably some special type, and you'd need to know what type if you want to replace it. You do need to replace it.

Comment: Looks like a good logo for a Notch Filter company called the "Black Hole"

Comment: @Hearth At that confirms my suspicion, thanks. I'll need to look around...